# c# Tcp client refused to connect to Nodemcu esp8266 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sockets, tcp

I am trying to connect Windows form application(tcp client) to the Tcp server app on android device,
 but i am getting the following error in image:

[No connection could be made as the target machine actively refused it at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcOlK.png)

And here is my C# code which i modified as per my application which i got from Microsoft site:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

My code:

```
namespace nodemcu_connection_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         // Client socket.  
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.  
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        // Receive buffer.  
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.  
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        private const int port = 80;

        static string ip = "192.168.43.142";
        static IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        static Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
        private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // The response from the remote device.  
        private static String response = String.Empty;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.StartClient();

        }

        private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }

        private void stopreceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Send(client, "READSTOP");
        }

        private void startreceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Send(client, "READSTART");
            Form1.Receive(client);
            textBox1.Text += response + "\n";
        }

        public static void StartClient()
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.  
            try
            {
                // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                // Send test data to the remote device.  
                /* Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
                 sendDone.WaitOne();

                 // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                 Receive(client);
                 receiveDone.WaitOne();

                 // Write the response to the console.  
                 Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);*/



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete the connection.  
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Signal that the connection has been made.  
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the state object.  
                Form1 state = new Form1();
                state.workSocket = client;

                // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Form1.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                Form1 state = (Form1)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.  
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Get the rest of the data.  
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Form1.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        response = state.sb.ToString();

                    }
                    // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
                //int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                //Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

                // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot of Tcp server app:
[There are some Diferrences in the ip addresses but the ip was as mentioned in program and the server had the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhz6M.jpg)

This was the testing one whether my app will connect to a Tcp server or not My aim is to achieve connection between nodemcu(esp8266) module and Windows Form app.

Comment: Are you considering ports on both ends?

Comment: Yes I used port 80 in the android tcp server app too...

Comment: Things you should check is:
1. Use other port number like

Comment: Is my rest of the code correct???

Comment: Things you should check is:
1. Use another port number like 8061
2. Turn off your firewall for a while.
And still, if you are facing the issues connect me over chat I can help you more on this as I am working on similar project.

Comment: ohk thank you @Mohammed Gadi i will try and contact you.

Comment: @mohammed gadi I am having problem in receiving the text into a Listbox/textbox but i can view the message in MessageBox.show(response); method.